# using gradient in fmin_bfgs

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization

I want to use calculated logistic regression, so I am using fmin_bfgs. 
However while trying to use the gradient, it gives error like this:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,25) (5,)
```

While not using fmin_bfgs, it computes the gradient fine.

Here is the part of my code:

```
theta, J = fmin_bfgs(costfunction, \
         initial_theta , fprime = gradient, args = (X,y==c,lmd))
all_theta[:,c] = theta
```

Here is how I calculate the gradient:

```
def gradient(theta,X,y,lmd):

  m = len(y)
  n = len(theta)
  z = np.dot((np.transpose(X)),theta)
  h = sigmoid(z)
  y = np.reshape( y , (-1,1))
  h.reshape(m,1)
  grad = np.dot( X , (h-y) )/m
  #print('grad shape %d'%(grad.shape))
  print('grad %d'%(grad))
  temp = theta
  temp[0] = 0
  grad = grad + (lmd/m)*temp
  return  grad
```

Comment: Could you add an example of data, best a function that generates data with some noise? See [mcve] on how make complete yet minimal working examples.

Comment: Please show the full traceback for the exception, not just the last line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your responses. I could figure out the problem. I had to remove the 'reshape' line from the 'gradient' function.

```
def gradient(theta,X,y,lmd):
 m = len(y)
 n = len(theta)
 z = np.dot(X , theta)
 h = sigmoid(z)
 #y = np.reshape( y , (-1,1)) <-- removed this
 #h.reshape(m,1) <-- removed this
 grad = np.dot( np.transpose(X) , (h-y) )/m
 temp = theta
 temp[0] = 0
 grad = grad + (lmd/m)*temp
 return  grad
```

Thank you everyone!